# Explanation of duration of forces due to electrostatic charge

Tags: electricity, everyday-life

when we use the pen and make the rubbing in it the pen can attractive the paper and after 1 sec. the paper fall down because it loss the earned energy 
but in this video the balloon still attractive in the wall

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsmVu6vmzlQ&feature=youtu.be

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsmVu6vmzlQ&feature=youtu.be
why the ball attached in the wall even if he push it

Comment: Please edit your question; the language is very vague.

Comment: Pen neutralize charge very quickly whereas it take time for wall and balloon pair to do so. It all depends on conductivity of materials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the pen and the balloon are both positively charged.

Initially the paper and the wall (connected to the Earth) will have negative and positive charge induced on them.

Since the induced negative charges are closer to the paper/balloon than the induced positive charges both the paper/balloon will be attracted to the pen/wall.

The paper being relatively smaller, lighter and moist, and hence a conductor, with gain positive charges from the pen and will eventually have enough positive charge on it to be repelled from the pen.

The balloon on the other hand is a much better insulator than paper and so the only charge which will be transferred to the wall will be at the point of contact between the balloon and the wall - relatively little.  So the balloon stays attracted to the wall.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case of static electricity. A charge is induced on the balloon through rubbing it on the fur. This charge then either repels or attracts the electron clouds in the wall therefore inducing a temporary charge on the molecules in the wall.

Now why does this not work with the pen and paper? Well it is a completely different scenario with different materials that is affected by a number of parameters. First, the mass of the paper in relation to the coulomb force established may vary from the ratio of these values in the balloon. Of course it is possible that the paper also loses its charge quicker than the balloon (it is not such a good insulator).

It would be interesting to see a video of the experiment with paper and pen to determine further differences to the youtube video because the underlying physics principle that allows the materials to "stick" to the wall is the same.